# Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed reason?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub tcptiff()

Dim TCP As String
Dim eebo As String
Dim tiff As String
Dim facpage As String

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

TCP = Range("F1").Value
tiff = Range("F2").Value
eebo = ActiveCell(0, 0).Value
facpage = ActiveCell(, 3).Value

If IsEmpty(Range(ActiveCell(, 3))) = False Then
    If Len(eebo) = 2 Then
        ActiveCell(, 1).Value = TCP & "-" & "00" & Left(eebo, 1) & "-" & Right(eebo, 1)
        ActiveCell(, 2).Value = tiff & "_Page_" & facpage

    ElseIf Len(eebo) = 3 Then
        ActiveCell(, 1).Value = TCP & "-" & "0" & Left(eebo, 2) & "-" & Right(eebo, 1)
        ActiveCell(, 2).Value = tiff & "_Page_" & facpage
    End If

End If

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

I'm trying to write an excel macro so that it fills out two columns with relevant information from adjacent cells. I wrote the macro in Sheet2 Code. I keep getting Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed. What is the problem? I tried to specify the worksheet, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: you have to set ws2 to an actual worksheet.  Just telling VBA that it's a worksheet doesn't cut it.

Comment: oops I uploaded the wrong copy. I tried ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") and added the ws2. to all the methods and objects, but the macro never ran. Thank you for your help though. Without the ws2. 's how would you fix the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
If IsEmpty(Range(ActiveCell(, 3))) = False Then
```

ActiveCell(, 3) is already a Range so :

```
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell(, 3)) = False Then
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was such a rookie mistake on my part